# Некорректно отображаются русские буквы Python/Kivy

Tags: python, кодировка, kivy

Прошу подсказать что исправить, чтобы при запуске корректно отображались **названия кнопок на русском языке**. PyCharm настроен на UTF8.
Благодарю.

Если что: Win10,64-bit, Python 3.8.0.
Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

Builder.load_file('itin.kv')


Window.size = (480, 800)

class Itin (AnchorLayout):
    pass


class Month (Button):
    pass


class Actor (Button):
    pass


class ItinApp (App):
    def build(self):
        return Itin ()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ItinApp ().run ()
```

## Файл itin.kv

```
<Itin>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Month: # Экземпляр
            id: _month
            text: 'Месяц...'
            size_hint: None,None
            width: root.width /2
            height: 50


    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Actor:
            id: _who_priest
            text: 'Сотрудник...'
            size_hint: None,None
            width: root.width /2
            height: 50

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        size_hint: None,None
        height: 40
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'share to...'
```

Answer (score 1):

Наконец-то! Все буквы на русском...

Идём по цепочке (Win10) и ставим "галку":

Параметры Windows -> Время и язык -> Язык -> Административные языковые параметры -> Изменить язык системы. Здесь ставим галочку "**Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире**" Перезагружаем компьютер.

PS Сам .kv-файл должен быть в кодировке UTF-8.

PPS Есть рекомендации использовать Notepad++ для смены кодировки, однако, для тех кто пользуется PyCharm, в правом нижнем углу есть кнопка кодировки. Удобно.